# puppet iteration with 2 dimensional array to fill template

Tags: puppet

I want to store ip address, port values in a two dimensional array.

```
192.168.1.156, 4100
192.168.1.157, 4000
```

Using the defined array, I want to fill this following template structure.

```
<members>
   <%- if @members -%>
   <%- @members.each_pair do |hostname,port| -%>
      <member>
           <hostName><%= hostname %></hostName>
           <port><%= port %></port>
      </member>
   <%- end -%>
   <%- end -%>
</members>
```

How do I construct the two dimensional array in my setup.pp or init.pp file?

Comment: The use of `each_pair` suggests that you actually want to use a hash, not a two-dimensional array. Is that correct?

Comment: @Felix 
Using a hash is not mandatory. Just want to use a hostname, port pair to fill my template. Didn't know `each_pair` implies of using a hash. Thanks for the info. 
Currently I'm only filling my templates with a hostnames array using `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make the most sense for you to declare your data in hash form. In Hiera, you can use YAML

```
members:
  192.168.1.156: 4100
  192.168.1.157: 4000
```

or JSON

```
{ members: { '192.168.1.156': '4100', '192.168.1.157': '4000' } }
```

If you don't want to use Hiera, you can declare the data right in the manifest.

```
$members = { '192.168.1.156' => '4100',
             '192.168.1.157' => '4000' }
```